# Easing effect for position:fixed div

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to add blog icon in my website 
its **position fixed ,bottom:50px; right 10px;**
At the time of page scroll, i want to add an easing effect on the icon(eg: some social media widgets available in wordpress  [socialmedia icon demo link](http://www.acurax.com/products/floating-social-media-icon-plugin-wordpress/)). At the time of scrolling, the icon must move up or down according to the scroll and later it must retain its position and settle.

Comment: Look for [CSS Transition Property](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) easing.

Comment: i need exactly like social media icons showing here -> http://www.acurax.com/products/floating-social-media-icon-plugin-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution 
 I hope it will help someone!
HTML

```
<a class="blog_button" href="#" title="Blog"><img src="images/blog_butn.png" alt="blog"></a>
```

CSS

```
.blog_button{
   position: absolute;
   right:0;
   top:50%;
   z-index: 5000;
 }
```

jQuery--

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){

     var bb= $(document).scrollTop();
     var ac_height=$( window ).height()/2.3;
     bb=parseInt(bb)+parseInt(ac_height);
     var h=bb+'px'
     $('.blog_button').animate({top:h},50);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

By using some `JS code` you can achieve that effect.

Here is the Js code used here.

```
$().ready(function() {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollingDiv");

        $(window).scroll(function(){            
            $scrollingDiv
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow" );          
        });
    });
```

CSS Used here

```
#scrollingDiv{background-color:red; padding:5px; font-size:15px; position:fixed; top:0; right:0;}
```

Here is the Working  Demo http://jsfiddle.net/SAVF7/9/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use position absolute instead of fixed and use this script:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $yourDiv = $("#scrollingDiv");
    $(window).scroll(function(){            
        $yourDiv.stop().animate({"marginTop":($(window).scrollTop() + 10) + "px"}, "300" );
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#scrollingDiv{background-color:green; padding:5px; font-size:15px; position:absolute; top:0; right:0;}
```

here is the **[fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SAVF7/19/)** for this:

Comment: i got the solutions  posted as answer below